# Using acetic acid to make vinegar

Tags: acid-base

I'm aware that a [very similar question has been answered](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/91339/is-it-advisable-to-make-vinegar-at-home-using-acetic-acid), however that only deals with powdered form and there is no information about food safety in there.

From what I understand, white vinegar is just acetic acid diluted with water. Where I live I cannot find anything stronger than a 5% distilled vinegar, neither in shops nor online (not even Amazon). I can however get a 99% acetic acid solution in liquid form. If I dilute this 1:8 with water it would give me a roughly 12.4% vinegar solution. My question is

1. Is it safe to consume acetic acid diluted with water?
2. Are there other processes or agents required to make a distilled vinegar that mixing acetic acid with water does not provide?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 12.5% is a very high concentration for food vinegar. But dilution of food grade acetic acid to produce vinegar is feasible and often done. The islamic restriction on brewing (which prohibits consumption of alcohol and naturally brewed vinegar) has led to the availability of "non-brewed condiment" which is, essentially, industrial acetic acid diluted to food-safe levels. (but needs food-grade acetic acid to start with).

Comment: 12% is basically the standard for white vinegar/vinegar essence in Europe, it's only in the US that you will have trouble finding these concentrations. It's not particularly high, and almost all recipes using this will have some amount of water and sugar as well. Good point about verifying that it is "food grade".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your first question,
I would recommend against trying to dilute 99% acetic acid to consume. First of all, the dilution of 99% acetic acid is dangerous without the proper precaution, as it will be highly exothermic and can cause hot acid to spray onto you. Second of all, your source of 99% acetic acid is most likely meant for use in a lab setting, not for human consumption. Although lab-grade materials tend to be purer than their food-grade counterparts, they may contain impurities that are not safe to be consumed and that would not be allowed in materials used for food. Additionally, consuming higher concentrations of acetic acid can be dangerous. According to this [case report](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5810867/#:%7E:text=Whilst%20lower%20concentrations%20of%202,renal%20failure%2C%20shock%20and%20death), "oral ingestion of greater than 12% has been reported to cause haemolysis, renal failure, shock and death".

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply and link to the article. 12% is pretty bog standard in most of Europe and US so I wouldn't be too worried about accidentally consuming 12.4% or even 13%, but the point about impurities not approved for food grade is a good reason to avoid it. I'll have to keep looking around then :) thanks very much!

Comment: Vinegar can be fermented from wine to about 12%.